# How/where is the marker layer added to the Google Map with the Gmap Module?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So,

I'm interested in trying to "export" a collection of markers from a Google Map generated by the Gmap module. Specifically, I'm looking for how to pull human-readable marker information from the js loaded into the page, not how to create an exportable list of the marker data.

From poking around in the javascript console, I can find what look like a series of related auto generated JS files in sites/default/files/js; but the JS looks like it contains the functions to create the markers and map definitions, not the geometry collection itself. Similarly, the gmap_markers.js doesn't provide much that's easy to decipher.

So, is drupal passing variables to those js scripts to create the markers on the fly? and if so, is there a place where a human-readable collection of those markers (ID, LatLon, popup info, and any other meta data) is stored and loaded into the Gmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got the answer from reddit.com/r/javascript. All the map settings are stored in the drupal.settings js variable, you can access it from the console in drupal.settings.gmap.auto1map.markers